# Is there a MX List itemRollOver event equivalent on a Spark List control?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml, flex-spark

Flex 3 List control had a itemRollOver event. Flex 4 List doesn't have it. Is there an equivalent or a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the roll over event within a custom item renderer and dispatch an event (custom or otherwise) that bubbles up.  I believe they removed the event for the sake of not dispatching unused events unless the developer specifies it.

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much it :)

Answer (score 2):

The itemRollOver and itemRollOut events have been added to the spark List in the Flex 4.5 release.

Comment: Thanks (: that's good to know. I've been discovering the solutions for some of my problems in your website.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff923c946c5112135c8ee9e-7fff.html  I do not see these.

Comment: These properties are documented here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ListBase.html